# Verify SSL Encryption for any given URL in python 2.7 (https)

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, pycharm, ssl-certificate

I want to find a correct way of verify that website is https enable by providing its url

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("www.python.org")
conn.request("GET", "/")
r1 = conn.getresponse()
print r1.status, r1.reason
data1 = r1.read()
conn.request("GET", "/")
r2 = conn.getresponse()
print r2.status, r2.reason
data2 = r2.read()
conn.close()
```

but i'm getting following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/muhammad.faisal/Documents/NLP/Main.py", line 54, in 
    conn.request("GET", "/")
  File "C:\Users\muhammad.faisal\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\httplib.py", line 1042, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Users\muhammad.faisal\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\httplib.py", line 1082, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Users\muhammad.faisal\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\httplib.py", line 1038, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Users\muhammad.faisal\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\httplib.py", line 882, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\muhammad.faisal\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\httplib.py", line 844, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\muhammad.faisal\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\httplib.py", line 1255, in connect
    HTTPConnection.connect(self)
  File "C:\Users\muhammad.faisal\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\httplib.py", line 821, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\muhammad.faisal\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\socket.py", line 557, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed

Comment: *"..getaddrinfo failed.."* - your DNS cannot does not resolve the hostname you have given to an IP address. This might be a problem of your DNS setup or that you have given the wrong name. In both cases the problem is not the Python code.

Comment: Error occurs after calling get call
conn.request("GET", "/")
r1 = conn.getresponse()
print r1.status, r1.reason
data1 = r1.read()
conn.request("GET", "/")
r2 = conn.getresponse()
print r2.status, r2.reason
data2 = r2.read()
conn.close()

Comment: With "problem is not the Python code" I mean that the reason the code is failing has nothing to do with your specific code, but is a result from either a bad DNS setup or the wrong domain given. Other applications might be affect by the same problem on the same system when accessing the same host.

Answer (score 0):

In tried to execute on my system. Its working corrrectly.

**In [8]: import httplib**

In [9]: conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("www.python.org")

In [10]: conn.request("GET", "/")

In [11]: r1 = conn.getresponse()

In [12]: print r1.status, r1.reason
200 OK

In [13]: data1 = r1.read()

In [14]: conn.request("GET", "/")

In [15]: r2 = conn.getresponse()

In [16]: print r2.status, r2.reason
200 OK

In [17]: data2 = r2.read()

In [18]: conn.close()

You have might be having problem in httplib package. Try installing again My python version is Python 2.7.6

Comment: Error occurs when my code reached to conn.request("GET","/")

Comment: Try uninstalling and installing httplib package again